# Symfony Command for MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, command

I am trying to create a Symfony command in which it runs a query and eventually run that as a cronjob.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Here is my code so far.  I am wondering where should i create my query at.

```
namespace KCM\GivingBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;





class GivingTranReport extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {

        $this
            ->setName('giving:report')
            ->setDescriptio('Runs query for giving transactions on hold')
        ;
    }

   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {





   }
```

Comment: There are tons of DQL examples on SO, did you search? You custom queries should go in your entity repository. As for the cron job, it's linux related.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to doctrine and symfony.

Comment: No worries, can tell. Anyway, DQL examples are all over the place, search some topics... It's hard to give you a proper answer as you give no real specifics on to what you want to do. So we can't really provide you with a DQL example

Answer (score -1):

Do something like:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $connection = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
    $connection->executeUpdate("UPDATE mytable SET mycol = 1 WHERE id = 1");
}
```